# get stuck in mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data

Tags: mysql, linux

When I use mysqld_safe to start my MySQL in CentOS7:

```
[root@localhost bin]# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 32586
[root@localhost bin]# 2017-09-07T13:29:36.423040Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/localhost.localdomain.err'.
2017-09-07T13:29:36.456574Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
```

It get stuck in the `mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon`.

I find the SO, do not find this post, and some similar, but is not stuck, they report error directly.

MySQL version is 5.7.19

My requirement is change the user `root`'s password.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At last, I find if change the mysql version greater than 5.7's password, we should not use the outdated method.

The correct method:

1. In the mysql config file `/etc/my.cnf`, add `skip-grant-tables` in the `[mysqld]`.
2. Restart mysql (`/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`)
3. Start mysql (`type mysql directly`)
4. Change the password of user(`root`)

   ```
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost'IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword'
   ```
5. Exit mysql and delete the `skip-grant-tables` in `/etc/my.cnf`
6. Then you can use `mysql -u root -p` to login the mysql now.

Comment: what is `direct input mysql` (in step 3) ?

Comment: @user2923322 direct input mysql, means you just type command mysql like >mysql

Answer (score 1):

To change the root's password, you can run `mysql_secure_installation`
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql_secure_installation/

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 18 and MySQL 5.7 configuration

- `nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
- add `skip-grant-tables` under `[mysqld]`
- `systemctl restart mysql`
- `mysql` Now you can change the password of root or any

And remove `skip-grant-tables` under `[mysqld]` after changing the password and again `systemctl restart mysql` for normal function.